# How does a django project use multiple databases with the same structure to read and write, distinguished by url

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

I have a django project and want to divide it into multiple databases with the same structure.

Use url to distinguish different databases. When the admin management page logs in, log in to different databases according to different urls.

For example: 127.0.0.1/admin uses the admin database, 127.0.0.1/admin2 uses the admin2 database.

Does django implement this function? What do I need to do, Can you give me some suggestions or ideas? thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
As far as a single django project is considered, there is no default way to achieve multiple database.

**Scenario 1**

From your very limited explaination I will assume that you want to seperate data of one admin dashboard from the data of second admin dashboard, to achieve data isolation with respect to permissions & other models, this is called multitenancy.

Very briefly: In a Multitenant architecture you can have multiple tenants whose structure is defined by your models.py and you can control all this tenant via a main superadmin, these tenants can have their own admin dashboard where the data stored in them are only specific to their tenant users. In more simpler terms you can have a SaaS app with this method, where you can have multiple organizations and these organizations have their own users with their specific permissions/groups.

Multitenancy can be achieved in django via a Schema seperated database using POSTGRESql and [this awesome package](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants) that has already done most of the heavy lifting for you. You can achieve seperate logins via url or subdomain. If your tenants have users who part of more than one organisation and you want a single login for all of them then you can use [this package](https://github.com/Corvia/django-tenant-users) that goes along with django-tenants. It provides a public user table with permission modules separate for each tenant.

**Scenario 2**

From your very limited explaination I will assume that you still want seperate databases for your app, in such case you need to rethink your approach to the problem because it is not something you will fancy after deployment as there is not direct way provided by django. Instead you should look into micro-service architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will study the method you said

Comment: Hi Ruchit Micro, Does django-tenants package not support mysql? My project has taken shape, and mysql is used, it feels not a good choice to replace POSTGREsql halfway。

Comment: Hi Ruchit Micro, I try to use multiple sites by inheriting AdminSite, and then allocate databases according to the sites (via database routing). This uses multiple databases. It seems to run without any problems. I don’t know if there will be hidden dangers and difficulties in the later period. maintain

Comment: Hello sorry for the delayed response, to answer your first question whether to change it to postgre, I will say that the package currently only supports postgres. I think you should consider this change because pg is very powerful and quite have the functionalities you will require in near future. Also because of migrations in django it is relatively easy to shift your MYSQL database to PG.

If you want we can connect me then feel free to reach out on my email ruchit@wolfx.io we will do a zoom call.